# Order Review Step before Payment Step in magento one page checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, orders, payment, review

I am looking for customization Magento Onepage checkout.I want order review step before payment step in Magento Onepage checkout.

So on click on the payment step the order should be created (or placed).but review step should be before payment step.

'login', 'billing', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'review' , 'payment';

I had gone through many articles on google every where their is code to remove review step and place order from the payment step.

Please give me an idea  how can i achieve this.